# No key with alias 'key' found in keystore flutter

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, deployment

I followed **flutter.div** instructions in how to deploy my app to google play, but im having a problem when i run **flutter build appbundle** in vs code, it says

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Failed to read key key from store "c:\Users\iikxz\upload-keystore.jks": No key with alias 'key' found in keystore c:\Users\iikxz\upload-keystore.jks

android/app/build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
```

android/key.properties:

```
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=key
storeFile= c:/Users/iikxz/upload-keystore.jks
```

Comment: What alias did you give the key when you created it?

Comment: If you just copied/pasted the command on the Flutter documentation, this one, `keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload`, then the alias would be _upload_ and not _key_

Answer (score 12):

If you just copied/pasted the command on the Flutter documentation, this one, `keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload`, then the alias would be `upload` and not `key`.